# C - Writing On Windows Compiling On UNIX And Vice Versa

Tags: c, windows, unix, compilation

I am planning to write an ANSI-C program on Windows with Netbeans using Cygwin suite, and later on i want to compile the source code on an UNIX family OS and use the program. Should i worry about any kind of compability problems?

Comment: Line terminations, make sure you use the correct format for each system/compiler.

Comment: Can you please explain more detailed?

Comment: UNIX systems terminate text-file lines with `\n` whereas windows favors `\r\n` line termination. You will likely need to convert between the two or find an option to switch the default type in Netbeans. Probably an option called newline character or line terminations.

Comment: @TheZ - using `\n` in C is *supposed* to mean "*The Line Terminator Whatever That Is*" unless you're doing binary mode (aka "raw") I/O (also google for [raw vs cooked terminal io]) i.e. writing the string "one line\n" to a file in text mode should write the correct platform line ending. The problem mainly appears when you move the written text file among systems, not when moving the source code.

Comment: @StephenP That is not true, I have switched systems and compilers before and had very cryptic errors thrown in response to the unexpected newline characters. So it _is_ something to look out for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use only the functionality described in the C standard, the set of possible incompatibilities typically reduces to:

- signedness of `char`
- sizes of **all** types (e.g. `int`=`long`=32-bit in Windows, not necessarily so on UNIX), I mean literally all, including pointers and `enums`
- poorly thought out type conversions and casts, especially involving pointers and negative values (mixing of signed and unsigned types in expressions is error-prone too)
- alignment of types and their padding in structures/unions
- endianness
- order of bitfields
- implementation-defined/specific behavior, e.g. right shifts of negative values, rounding and signs when dividing signed values
- floating-point: different implementation and different optimization
- unspecified behavior, e.g. orders of function parameter and subexpression evaluation, the direction in which `memcpy()` copies data (low to high addresses or the other way around), etc etc
- undefined behavior, e.g. `i+i++` or `a[i]=i++`, modifying string literals, pointer dereference when the object it's pointed to is gone (e.g. `free()'d`), not using or misusing `const` and `volatile`, etc etc
- supplying standard library functions with inappropriate parameters leading to undefined behavior, e.g. calling `printf()`-like functions with wrong number or kind of parameters
- non-ASCII characters/strings
- filename formats (special chars, length, case sensitivity)
- clock/time/locale formats/ranges/values/configuration

There's much more. You actually have to read the standard and note what's guaranteed to work and what's not and if there are any conditions.

If you use something outside of the C standard, that functionality may not be available or identical on a different platform.

So, yes, it's possible, but you have to be careful. It's usually the assumptions that you make that make your code poorly portable.

Answer (score 1):

There will be comparability problems, but as long as you stick to basic unix functionality, they ought to be manageable for command line applications. However, if your app has a GUI or has to interact with other programs in the unix environment, you'll probably regret your approach.

Another way to go would be to run the appropriate flavor of unix in a virtualbox on your desktop, and be pretty sure there are no compatibility problems.

Comment: Thank you. And one more question, is it same for vice versa? I mean writing on UNIX compiling on Windows.

Comment: I've only worked in the windows->unix direction, but as long as you stick to the least common denominator subset you should be ok.  The easy things you'll have to deal with are line endings, int size, file naming conventions and so on.